# Calculating div height for auto scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have defined divs called "slide-1" and "slide-2", with an intermediate span called "option-1" if the first button is clicked.

I would like to change the 195 and 268 (see below) in my scrollTop animation to calculated numbers based on the height of the "slide" divs, but when I try ("#slide-2").height() for example it doesnt seem to work.

Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dxysh/pen/kXpJYK) of what I have so far, it works exactly as I want, but I'm worried that once I add it to a webpage I'll have to change the scrollTop numbers manually again

Right now, the scrolling is based on those numbers I input myself

```
 //first option code

 $("#option-1-button").on("click", function() {
     $(this).closest(".box").find("#option-1").slideToggle();

     $('body').animate({scrollTop: 195}, 1000);

     $("#slide-2").delay(500).fadeToggle(1000);

     $('body').delay(500).animate({scrollTop: 268}, 1000);

     $('#option-1-button').prop('disabled', true);
     $('#option-2-button').prop('disabled', true);

 });
```

Comment: Please show the code that's causing trouble, rather than the code that works. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the $ sign:

```
  $('body').animate({ //animate element that has scroll
        scrollTop: $("#slide-1").height() //for scrolling
    }, 1000);

    $("#slide-2").delay(500).fadeToggle(1000);

    $('body').delay(500).animate({ //animate element that has scroll
        scrollTop: $("#slide-2").height() //for scrolling
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of a div using offset();
It will give you the top or left position of an element. (pixels from top or left of document 0,0) then just scroll to that value.

e.g. $('#slide-1').offset().top;

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to notice here -

1. Duplicate `ID` values. You have 2 elements with `id="windows"`. Change those to classes, otherwise your height will be off.
2. Because you will now have multiple `windows` elements, they may all have different heights, so you will need to rely on index values to determine which `windows` height you will get.
3. You need to get the height of 3 different things -

   - The height of the `option` box to the top of the window
   - The height of the `option` box itself including margin
   - The height of the `windows` element including margin

---

```
var window = $('.windows')[0]  //0 is the index of the first occurrence of the class windows

var scrollHeight = $('#option1').offset().top + $('#option1').outerHeight(true) + $(window).outerHeight(true);
```

I utilized the jQuery method `.outerHeight([includeMargin])` and set the `includeMargin` flag to `true` so it would include any margin which would be necessary in the calculation of height - http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

Edited demo as well - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZKrWQ